# What happens if you reach the gold with both (blue and green) doors?

Tags: saboteur-2

If you construct a path from a ladder to an end card with a blue or green door in the path, the end card is flipped. If the card is the gold, all dwarves on that colored team (blue or green) win, as does the boss and profiteer.

What happens if you construct a path from a ladder to an end card while *both* doors are in the path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Since the scoring depends on the player combination, I will discuss on four different cases. The scoring rules are summarized at the bottom of this post.*

### **Situation:**

- Route to gold is blocked with both, **green** and **blue door.** This immediately implies that no blue or green team can win. Players in blue or green team will get no points.
- A player (**Any player**: Blue, Green, Boss, Geologist, Profiteur or Saboteur) makes a connection to the gold, and flips the card.

---

### **CASE 1**

- Players in the round are two Green diggers, Blue digger, Boss,
  Saboteur and Geologist.

--> **Only Boss will win**. (Green and Blue are blocked by doors. Saboteur wins only if gold is not found. Geologist is never a loser or a winner). Since there is only one winner, it will mean 5 points. Since the winner is the boss, he gets *one point less*, and receives **4 points**.

---

### **CASE 2**

- Players in the round are two Green diggers, Blue digger, Boss, Saboteur, Geologist and Profiteur.

--> **Boss and Profiteur will win**. (Green and Blue are blocked by doors. Saboteur wins only if gold is not found. Geologist is never a loser or a winner). Since there are two winners, it will mean 4 points for each. Boss will get *one point less*, and receives **3 points**. Profiteur gets always *two points less*, and receives **2 points**.

---

### **CASE 3**

- Players in the round are two Green diggers, Blue digger,  Saboteur, Geologist and Profiteur.

--> **Only Profiteur will win**. (Green and Blue are blocked by doors. Saboteur wins only if gold is not found. Geologist is never a loser or a winner). Since there is only one winner, it will mean 5 points. Since the winner is the profiteur, he gets *two points less*, and receives **3 points**.

---

### **CASE 4**

- Players in the round are two Green diggers, two Saboteurs, and two Geologist.

--> **Nobody wins.** Only geologists will collect points this round. If three gems are visible, both geologists will get one point.

---

The rules for the points are: (All rules without links are taken from the rulebook. Other rules are confirmed by Frederic Moyersoen behind the respective link.).

- **Green, Blue**: Wins, if hes/hers team member makes a connection to the gold. (And there are doors blocking the way).
- **Boss**: [Wins, if there is a connection to the gold](https://boardgamegeek.com/article/6675274#6675274). Gets always one point less.
- **Profiteer**: Wins always. Gets two points less.
- **Saboteur**: Wins, if the gold card is never flipped.
- **Geologist**: Never loses or wins. Only collects as many points as there are gems visible ([connected to the tunnel or not.](https://boardgamegeek.com/article/7735083#7735083)). [If "Trapped!", does not collect points](https://boardgamegeek.com/article/9828023#9828023).

Note that a "Trapped!" player is not counted as a winner.

Answer (score 7):

The game designer, **Frederic Moyersoen**, discusses the [answer to that question on BGG](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/6675274#6675274). Essentially, only the Boss wins

> If there is a path with a blue and green door, the boss is the only player who can win through this path (4 points). This can be a winning strategy for the boss.

Comment: Of course, I guess the Profiteer also wins.

Answer (score -3):

You say that the geologist never wins or looses. But the rule says:

.Both teams win (along with all other “non-Saboteurs”) if The Boss, The Geologist or The Profiteer creates the connection to the gold and the way there isn‘t blocked by a door of the other color.

"Win (along with all other non-saboteurs)" makes me understand that geologist is also counted as a winner.

Comment: That refers just to Blue/Green minders and The Geologist/Boss/Profiteer are not on a team. It should also be remembered that it is possible for the  The Geologist/Boss/Profiteer to get no gold based on the number of winners and condition of the board.