# What if the boss or the profiteur connect to the gold?

Tags: saboteur-2

I have this situation:

The boss has flipped the gold card with a path card. The path there was blocked by both a green and a blue card. We had one profiteur, a blue dwarf, a green dwarf, a sabotuer and a boss.

Who wins and how much gold?

I found [this post](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/6675274#6675274) with an answer to a different question by the creator of the game, where it states that the boss would get 4 points but I am still confused, I can't find it anywhere on the rules how the boss would get 4 points from this situation.
More than that, what if the profiteer flips the gold card, what happens then?

**EDIT : I'm still confused.** Rules say that if ONLY ONE dwarf wins, he wins 5 gold, if 2 dwarves win, then it's 4 gold each. Why does he win 4 gold? Does the profiteer also win if he is the one flipping the gold card? How much? Do they both get 4 gold each? 5 gold to boss and 3 to profiteer or what?
**EDIT2 :** So if I have a blue dwarf, a boss and a profiteer in the game, there's just 1 dwarf counted as winner, that's 5 gold for him, 4 for boss and 3 for profiteer. But if I have just a boss and a profiteer, if any of them flip the gold card, then it's 2 winners and they get 3 - boss and 2 - profiteer? In conclusion when there's no dwarves to get to the gold, boss and profiteer are both counted as winning dwarves regardless, but when there are colored dwarves, then these two are not included as winners? I don't even want to include geologists in these situation..

My opinion is that you can interpret these rules as you want and that's a huge slip from the creator. I for one, agree that if neither saboteurs or colored dwarves get to the gold, then noone gets anything (except geologists where it's clear what they get). This messy slip up can **REALLY ruin friendships**...

Comment: I think you're mistaken about "blue dwarf, boss and profiteer" counting as 1 winner - that's 3 winners, so 3 gold for the blue dwarf, 2 for the boss, 1 for the profiteer.  See the gold distribution example on the last page of the rulebook.  The number of winners is always simply the number of dwarves who are eligible for a share of the booty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's clear that the rules are a little badly worded.  They say:

> The Boss builds tunnels for both the Green and the Blue Team and wins
>   every time one of the teams wins.

However, the game's creator has made it clear that in the corner case, where the path is completed but both the Blue and Green teams are blocked by a door, the Boss wins anyway (even though it is not true that "one of the teams wins").

I think that the Profiteer wins in this situation too - the Profiteer ALWAYS wins, after all...

See this [old question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/6928/what-happens-if-you-reach-an-end-card-with-both-doors) - in fact now I read that, I'm a bit worried that this question may count as a duplicate...

ETA: I think if one dwarf wins, they get 5 Gold.  If one dwarf wins and he's the Boss, he gets 4 Gold.  If two dwarves win, and they're the Boss and the Profiteer, they would get 4 gold each, minus their respective "job penalties": so 3 Gold for the boss and 2 Gold for the profiteer.  Seems like a reasonable interpretation of the creator's assertion that the Boss winning on his own gets 4 Gold (assuming he didn't just pluck that figure out of thin air...)

In short, I'd say that the "1 or 2 less than the other winners get" (for the boss and profiteer) is another sloppily worded piece of rules.  "1 or 2 less than they would otherwise get" would be a better way of putting it.  If the Profiteer won on his own, for example, he'd get 3 Gold (5-2).

Comment: Sorry, but this didn't answer my question at all, I added an edit.

Comment: @Andrei Edited to answer your edit!

Comment: Ok, your interpretation makes sense, but would that make the boss and profiteer cards a little too overpowered? One more thing, I made another edit, with a new situation, as your interpretation rises more questions.

Comment: @AndreiCristianProdan Your new edit does not change anything. If there is a blue and green door on the winning path, then the blue dwarf does NOT count as a winner, only the boss/profiteer do. If there was only a blue door on the path, then the blue dwarf would count as a winner, and the gold would be split between the 3 of them.

Answer (score 1):

**CASE**: Players in the round are Profiteur, Blue dwarf, Green dwarf, a Saboteur and the Boss.

--> **Boss and Profiteur will win**. (Green and Blue are blocked by doors. Saboteur wins only if gold is not found. Boss wins if there is a connection to the gold. Profiteour wins always). Since there are two winners, it will mean 4 points for each. Boss will get *one point less*, and receives **3 points**. Profiteur gets always *two points less*, and receives **2 points**.

Comment: See also my answer to this question: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/6928/what-happens-if-you-reach-an-end-card-with-both-doors